# How to get millisecond between two dateTime obj?

Tags: php, datetime

How to get millisecond between two `DateTime` objects?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime("1990-08-07 08:44");
```

I tried to follow the comment below, but I got an error.

```
$stime = new DateTime($startTime->format("d-m-Y H:i:s"));
$etime = new DateTime($endTime->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")); 
$millisec = $etime->getTimestamp() - $stime->getTimestamp();`
```

I get the error

> Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimestamp()

Answer (score 19):

In the strict sense, you can't.

It's because the smallest unit of time for the DateTime class is a second.

If you need a measurement containing milliseconds then use [microtime()](http://us.php.net/microtime)

---

**Edit:**

On the other hand if you simply want to get the interval in milliseconds between two [ISO-8601 datetimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) then one possible solution would be

```
function millisecsBetween($dateOne, $dateTwo, $abs = true) {
    $func = $abs ? 'abs' : 'intval';
    return $func(strtotime($dateOne) - strtotime($dateTwo)) * 1000;
}
```

Beware that by default the above function returns absolute difference. If you want to know whether the first date is earlier or not then set the third argument to false.

```
// Outputs 60000
echo millisecsBetween("2010-10-26 20:30", "2010-10-26 20:31");

// Outputs -60000 indicating that the first argument is an earlier date
echo millisecsBetween("2010-10-26 20:30", "2010-10-26 20:31", false);
```

On systems where the size of time datatype is 32 bits, such as Windows7 or earlier, millisecsBetween is only good for dates between `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and `2038-01-19 03:14:07` (see [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).

Comment: So does $date = new DateTime();

Comment: Are you sure DateTime uses a UNIX timestamp internally? I thought it could represent a wider range of dates.

Comment: @JW: Although I was thinking more along the lines of a format as having a specific smallest unit, you make a valid point. The actual values for DateTime can certainly go below 1970 and referring to the UNIX timestamp might suggest otherwise. Fixed it.

Comment: `DateTime` currently supports sub-second precision - for example: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", "1234567890.987654")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")` outputs `2009-02-13 23:31:30.987654`.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to digg out an old question, but I've found a way to get the milliseconds timestamp out of a DateTime object:

```
function dateTimeToMilliseconds(\DateTime $dateTime)
{
    $secs = $dateTime->getTimestamp(); // Gets the seconds
    $millisecs = $secs*1000; // Converted to milliseconds
    $millisecs += $dateTime->format("u")/1000; // Microseconds converted to seconds
    return $millisecs;
}
```

It requires however that your DateTime object contains the microseconds (u in the format):

```
$date_str = "20:46:00.588";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s.u", $date_str);
```

This is working only since PHP 5.2 hence the microseconds support to DateTime has been added then.

With this function, your code would become the following :

```
$date_str = "1990-08-07 20:46:00.588";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", $date_str);

$msNow = (int)microtime(true)*1000;

echo $msNow - dateTimeToMilliseconds($date1);
```

Comment: Very good answer! However, there is a small mistake in the example. I had to add some parentheses to make the microtime is multiplied before the cast to integer, like so: `$msNow = (int)(microtime(true)*1000);`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime supports microseconds since 5.2.2. This is mentioned in the documentation for the date function, but bears repeating here. You can create a DateTime with fractional seconds and retrieve that value using the 'u' format string.

```
<?php
// Instantiate a DateTime with microseconds.
$d = new DateTime('2011-01-01T15:03:01.012345Z');

// Output the microseconds.
echo $d->format('u'); // 012345

// Output the date with microseconds.
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'); // 2011-01-01T15:03:01.012345

// Unix Format
echo "<br>d2: ". $d->format('U.u');

function get_data_unix_ms($data){
    $d = new DateTime($data);
    $new_data = $d->format('U.u');
    return $new_data;
}

function get_date_diff_ms($date1, $date2)
    {
        $d1 = new DateTime($date1);
        $new_d1 = $d1->format('U.u');

        $d2 = new DateTime($date2);
        $new_d2 = $d2->format('U.u');

        $diff = abs($new_d1 - $new_d2);

        return $diff;
    }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score -2):

Here's a function to do that + tests.

https://gist.github.com/vudaltsov/0bb623b9e2817d6ce359eb88cfbf229d

Comment: Short answers with urls are considered low quality as the external link can change or break. Please see [answer] and edit your answer to include the key details from the link.

Answer (score -3):

DateTime dates are only stored as whole seconds. If you still need the number of milliseconds between two DateTime dates, then you can use getTimestamp() to get each time in seconds (then get the difference and turn it into milliseconds):

```
$seconds_diff = $date2.getTimestamp() - $date.getTimestamp()
$milliseconds_diff = $seconds_diff * 1000
```

Comment: I probably could have mentioned what Saul mentioned :)

Comment: +1 since this really is the only method (in concept at least) to take two second-precision dates and get the number of milliseconds between them...

Comment: @Saul hehe.. 1 second is 1000 milliseconds.. it's not going to get you any more precision than seconds, but it is a valid answer.

Comment: @Fosco: Yup, I was thinking about precision but looking at your 1st comment at the same time, hence the mixup.

Comment: sorry this get an error

$stime = new DateTime($startTime->format("d-m-Y H:i:s"));
        $etime = new DateTime($endTime->format("d-m-Y H:i:s"));
        $millisec = $etime->getTimestamp() - $stime->getTimestamp();

"Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimestamp()"

Comment: It seems unlikely the OP was wanting simply to show full seconds with milliseconds. You should at least clean up the math.