# PHP How to subtract two dates with milliseconds

Tags: php, date, subtraction

For example:

```
$date1='2017-12-13 13:06:21.602';
$date2='2017-12-13 13:06:18.102';
$diff=$date1-$date2
echo $diff;
```

output should be 3.5

Comment: previously answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027050/2067753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution 5.2.2 < php version < 7.1

```
<?php
$date1=\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u','2017-12-13 13:06:21.602');
$date2=\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u','2017-12-13 13:06:18.102');
// $di =  $date1->diff($date2);
// var_dump( $di );

// seconds
$diffSeconds = $date1->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp();
// milli
$diffMilli = ($date1->format('u') - $date2->format('u')) / 1000000;
//result :
$diffWithMilli = $diffSeconds + $diffMilli;
var_dump($diffWithMilli);
```

Comment: var_dump($diffWithMilli) giving me float(3.5)
How can i get only 3.5 ?

Comment: `echo $diffWithMilli;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [The DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Note: This solution works since PHP 7.1.0 when was added parameter `f`.

```
// your code goes here
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-12-13 13:06:21.602');
$date2 = new DateTime('2017-12-13 13:06:18.102');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $interval->s+$interval->f;  
// s = seconds, f = microseconds, as a fraction of a second

//var_dump($interval);
```

The result is 3.5

https://ideone.com/kf1PQQ

For PHP version comparison since 4.3.0: https://3v4l.org/VCI6P

Comment: I'm getting only 3 (insted 3.5) , why??

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: The F and `f` format characters were added in PHP version 7.1.0

Comment: Getting the same with  7.0, was thinking DI wasn't considering usecs (my comments). `7.1.0  The f property was added.` ok, nice to know. up+

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.3.173

Comment: I  have updated the answer with the minimal version needed.

Comment: Added link to the same code executed within all PHP versions since 4.3.0 https://3v4l.org/VCI6P